# Electrical siding pass through removal

Tags: electrical, pool

I have a outdoor switch that controls my spa pump. As you can see in the photo, one of the armored pump electric cables is not threaded to the box. It was like this when I bought the house. The box is too close to the wall to turn the armored cable nut, so I need to pull the box out from the wall a bit.

The next picture shows the back (I have already removed the ground clamp and strain relief). As far as I can tell, I need to put a pipe wrench on that metal conduit and turn it counterclockwise so I can get at the ring clamp holding the box to the wall. I gave it the full muscle try and could not get that conduit to turn. Am I doing the right thing? Do I just need more force on the wrench? Is there a recommended fluid like PB Blaster I can use in there around the wires? Or does this come apart in some other way? It cannot be turning the box on the outside, because the armored cable prevents that.

[image: ![Outside]

[image]

Comment: Picture leaves a little doubt - is that a short *female-thread both ends* coupling attached to a male thread sticking out of the wall with the nut ("ring clamp") on it as well as the coupling?

Comment: Are you sure you can't get a wrench on that nut and turn it 1/8 - 1/4 turn at a time, just as it is? Sure, it'll be slow going getting it tightened up, but I'd bet you can do that with less time than you've already invested trying to get the thing off the wall.

Comment: The picture of the interior appears to show a sealant between the conduit and the siding. Can you tell if it is caulk (Soft if poked with a screwdriver.) or perhaps epoxy (Hard.)?

Comment: Ecnerwal, yes that’s what I see. So it is box -> male/male nipple -> female/female conduit -> strain relief.

Comment: FreeMan: the conduit is tightened up to the nut (what I called the ring clamp) so it can’t turn unless the conduit backs off.

Comment: HABO: what looks like sealant is a metal ring, like a washer for the conduit nut. It is bent in because that conduit nut is really cranked on there.

Comment: If that box is aluminium it's not going to come off in one piece,

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off the power to this circuit (hopefully you already thought of
   that.)
2. Take off the cover of the box on the outside.
3. Take another picture, but it would be quite normal to find screws holding the box to the building **as well as** the conduit. Loosen or remove those screws, that may give you enough motion to do what you need to do.
4. If you resort to lubricants/penetrants, remove the wires first. Then use the petroleum products, then clean everything up before reinstalling the wires.

Comment: There are no screws holding the box to the wall, just the conduit on the back of the box.

Comment: A: bigger wrench. Though you might also need something holding the box on the outside as well. B: remove the wiring. apply heat (don't set the building on fire - use care) and penetrants and the bigger wrench. C: Use "not your nicest" flathead screwdriver and a hammer on the gaps in the conduit nut to turn it. Or file/grind the point of a big fat nail if all your screwdrivers are nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to tackle this would be to get a sharp wood chisel and take a small scoop out of the siding, directly behind the box connector for the armored cable. This will allow you to push the nut up to the fitting and thread it in. Everything else seems so nicely/permanently done it would be a shame to take it apart. You probably wont be able to see the chiseled divot much, behind the fitting...